# Maintain unique id across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a database-wide unique id.  That unique id should be one field of every row in every table of that database.

There are a few approaches I have considered:

- Create one master-table with an auto-increment-field and a trigger in every other table, like:

  "before insert here, insert in master-table -> get the auto-increment value -> and use this value as primary-key here"

  I have seen this before, but instead of making one INSERT, it does 2 INSERTS, which I expect would not be that performant.
- Add a field `uniqueId` to every table, and fill this field with a PHP-generated integer... something like unix-timestamp plus a random number.

  But I had to use `BIGINT` as the datatype, which means big `index_length` and big `data_length`.
- Similar to the "uniqueId" idea, but instad of `BIGINT` I use `VARCHAR` and use `uniqid()` to populate this value.

Comment: What is the purpose of the database-wide unique id? If every table has a primary key, then every row already has a unique id composed of tablename.pkey.

Comment: This is an awful, awful idea, and can only lead to pain and misery.

Comment: I have thought about this several times, for stuff like making (nearly) every element on a page commentable, or even for ratings on every element. I always thought this would make things easy.

@Ignacio: im not talking about using this as primary-key, if you thought so. Why do u think a unique identifier through multiple tables is that bad?

Comment: If they're not the primary key then why have them at all? You're just denormalizing your data otherwise.

Comment: @Ignacio:

Just a simple example...

PostsTable:
{ id | headline | text | uniqueElementId }

CommentsTable:
{ id | uniqueElementId | comment }

And then:
{ SELECT comment FROM CommentsTable WHERE uniqueElementId = $theUniqueId }

... something would be fascinating me, doin it this way.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. Consider a tables of users and user groups. Then a table of roles. You should be able to link both individual users and user groups to roles. There are a couple of different solutions to this but one way would be to have a globally unique id paralell with the primary key. If these keys in turn are listed in a table of it's own, you could even make the links directionless.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for opinions...  Of the three ideas you give, I would "vote" for the `uniqid()` solution.  It seems pretty low cost in terms of execution (but possibly not implementation).

A simpler solution (I think) would be to just add a field to each table to store a guid and set the default value of the field to be MySQL's function that generates a guid (I think it is UUID).  This lets the database do the work for you.

And in the spirit of coming up with random ideas... It would be possible to have some kind of offline process fill in the IDs asynchronously. Make sure every table has the appropriate field and make the default value be 0/empty.  Then the offline process could simply run a query on each table to find the rows that do not yet have a unique id and it could fill them in.  That would let you control the ID and even use some kind of incrementing integer.  This, of course, requires that you do not need the unique ID instantly each time a record is inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, mark. my personal favorite solution, until now, is the BIGINT solution, cause im a little afraid of uniqid() producing anytime an id that is just not unique. i also like your idea of mysql's UUID()... but this would be a really long string. the unix_timestamp + random number with a maximum of 9 numbers, would be nearly 50% smaller and its practically impossible to generate an id that is not unique...